# Grails scaffolding content

Tags: grails

How can I create scaffolding controller and see its code in order to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a domain class `Thing` in package `com.foo.bar` that you want to scaffold for, run

```
grails generate-all com.foo.bar.Thing
```

to create a scaffolded controller and GSPs, and a unit test for the controller.